# How secure admin account

Tags: security

I am working on a project whose admin has access on all controls of form but others cannot not. How can I can implement this?

One idea is when user wants to login with admin then before login software must check whether internet services are available if internet services are available then mail the time that must pick from google server and mail that timing with login information. so admin must alert that someone login with your account.

But if the internet services are not available there then kept that information in a text file which must place in the system and when services available then simply admin take that log file and ask user whose login with admin?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you use logging in your application and configure it to do whatever you want when pages with sensitive information are accessed. You can use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html), [Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff647183.aspx) or [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). This way, you can store the information in text or Xml files, database, send emails, etc.

`C#` example using `log4net`:

```
private static log4net.ILog oLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                if (this.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
                {
                    oLog.Info("Administrator logged in.");
                }
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```